# How to "turn" a page when asking for athlete activities in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, api, strava

In the Strava API, we can get the list Athlete Activities. However, we can only get 200 activities by page. I wonder how to get the other activities on the other pages?

I play with the parameters. When I put the `per_page` parameter to 1. I only get one activity even if the `page` parameter is to 60. 
As I am on NodeJs, I'm using fetch to call the API.

```
     api.getRefreshToken("REFRESH_TOKEN").then(strava => {

                    const headers = {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': "Bearer " + strava.access_token
                    };
                    fetch("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&page=60", {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: headers
                    }).then(responses => {
                        return responses.json();
                    }).then(
                        strava0 => {
                            console.log("Activities");
                            console.log(strava0);
                        });

                });
```

I would like to have the 60 activities I should normally have. However, I only get one.

Comment: *"I only get one"* - what did you expect from `per_page=1`? "Per page" is the number of records... per page, if you want more than 1 set it to more than 1!

Comment: I want to access to the other pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Strava API the maximum value of `per_page` (number of item per page) is `200` so you can set `per_page=200` to limit the number of API call.

If you have more than 200 activities, you have to send multiple requests using `page` parameter (i.e.: `page=1` for activities 1-200; `page=2` for activities 201-400).